# Visio - "add" shape patterns

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I have a short question regarding shape patterns in Visio 2013.

I created the following image with Visio 2013 - it's basically two rectangles with different background patterns.

[image: two rectangles with different background patterns]

What I want to do is the following:

> in the overlapping area, I want the background patterns to "add up".

I already tried changing opacity, but this didn't lead to the wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is possible** - though not obvious how to accomplish.

First, start off with the shape as you have it.

[image]

You commented that changing the opacity didn't work. That's because in the UI the opacity is set for **both** the foreground color (the red lines) and the background color (the white space between them).

However, by using the ShapeSheet, you can set them individually.

So, right-click on the top shape and select Show ShapeSheet.

[image]

Then navigate to the **Fill Format** section and notice the value for **FillBkgndTrans**.

[image]

Change the value for **FillBkgndTrans** to **THEMEGUARD(100%)**

[image]

And then you'll get the effect you want.

[image]